# How to change the background of only one button when clicked?

Tags: android, button, selector

I am generating my buttons programmatically.I want to change the background of the clicked button to `menuitemsactivity_button_backgrnd`.

The default background of the buttons is `popup`. I have done the following coding but the problem is that when I click the first button it changes its background, then when I click the second button the second button changes its background but the first button has the same `menuitemsactivity_button_backgrnd` background.

What I want to do is change the background of only the clicked button i.e at a time only one button has `menuitemsactivity_button_backgrnd` background.

I am posting my codes please guide me step by step:

```
            final Button tv1 = new Button(this);
            tv1.setId(i);
            tv1.setText(value);
            tv1.setTextSize(35);

            tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#1569C7"));
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.popup));
            tv1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300,90));
            tv1.setOnClickListener(getOnClickDoSomething(tv1)); 
            l1.addView(tv2);


          private OnClickListener getOnClickDoSomething(final Button tv1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             return new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String text = tv1.getText().toString();

                Log.e("text message", "" + text);
                tv1.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menuitemsactivity_button_backgrnd));
                Toast.makeText(MenuItemsActivity.this, "clicked"+v.getId()+","+tv1.getId(), 1000)
                        .show();


            }
        };
}
```

menuitemsactivity_button_backgrnd

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"     
      android:drawable="@drawable/blue_tab"
       />

    </selector>
```

Comment: please share the screen image of what you have and how you want?

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this :

```
"<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"     
  android:drawable="@drawable/blue_tab"
   />
 <item android:state_pressed="false"     
  android:drawable="@drawable/whatever_the_unselected_drawable_is"
   />
</selector>"
```